# If $u$ and $v$ are vectors in $3$-space, then $u\cdot v$ is a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations, cross-product

[image]

My understanding is that B is definitely true because of the below picture but I cannot understand A. Please would someone point me to the right direction! Thanks!
[image]

Comment: What does the dot product do?  What is a scalar?

Comment: What do you know about the dot product? That is, what is the result of $a\cdot b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u,v$ be vectors in $\mathbf{R}^3$. Then, the dot product is given by $\|u\|\|v\|\cos\theta$. This is a real number. Is that a scalar?

Here's a nice exercise - prove statement $\mathrm{B}.$: $u\cdot(u\times v)=v\cdot(u\times v)=0$.

Comment: Oh haha Im laughing at myself ok.. So A is true duh cause the dot product will equal a a real number(scalar). Great thanks for clearing that up!

Comment: @Abbid'AgneldeBourbon No problem!

Comment: To those who wish to remove the exercise: the OP said $\mathrm{B}.$ is true since he/she saw it in his/her textbook or some online resource. My question is asking the OP to provide a proof of the statement. It is _not ridiculous_, as one editor suggested in an edit he/she tried to make to this answer.